# Check if application is being run with ASLR enabled

Tags: aslr

On my system I have multiple applications running using:

`/bin/setarch linux32 -R <application + params>`

or:

`/bin/setarch linux32 <application + params>`

In order to enable/disable address space layout randomization.

Is there a way to see if a specific application uses ASLR or not, without having to look at the memory maps?

Comment: ptracing the application (with gdb) to query the state looks a bit frail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -R option sets a bit in the 'personality' flag of the process.

```
cat /proc/<pid>/personality
```

will display this flag. If the 19th bit is '1', then ASLR will be disabled. Else it is enabled.